# Iron (II, III) oxide and concentrated nitric acid

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox

[According to the Russian Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B4_%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0(II,III)), the reaction goes as follows:

$$\ce{Fe3O4 + 10HNO3 -> 3Fe(NO3)3 + NO2 + 5H2O}$$

Since $\ce{Fe3O4}$ is [often written out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron(II,III)_oxide) as $\ce{Fe2O3*FeO}$, why don't we have instead

$$\ce{Fe3O4 + 8HNO3 -> Fe(NO3)2 + 2Fe(NO3)3 + 4H2O}$$

Why does the reaction evolve gaseous nitrogen dioxide?

Comment: Because nitric acid is a powerful oxidizer, and when it sees something to oxidize, it does not think twice.

Comment: @IvanNeretin - thank you! Can one write an answer [based on this section of the electrode potentials table](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xPQho.png), I wonder. NO3(-) more actively wants to become NO2 gas than Fe(3+) wants to become Fe(2+).

Comment: @IvanNeretin - I want to try and write an answer to make myself memorize the reaction.

Comment: You don't memorize reactions. Also, I'm not sure whether you should memorize the electrode potentials table (I, for one, do not). I just have a vague feeling about some oxidants being "strong" and the others "weak", and that's enough for most situations.

Comment: @IvanNeretin - so this reaction cannot be explained using the potentials table?

Comment: Why, of course it can. The table tells you just the same as I did, only with more confidence.

Comment: "Guess" is not quite the right word either. Do you really mean $\ce{Mn3N2}$, the _nitride_? OK, this seems to be an acid-base reaction, $\ce{HCl}$ is an acid, and $\ce{N^{3-}}$ is a mighty strong base, so...

Comment: Sorry, Mg3N2 + HCl. I looked it up, and it produces HN4Cl - I would never have guessed (or reasoned) that out. (0:

Comment: Again, the reasoning is pretty straightforward, and there are just no gaps to be filled with guesswork. It is acid+base. What is the acid here? What is the base? What happens between the two?

Comment: @IvanNeretin - but why not just NH3? Why all the way to HN4Cl? What if we have not enough Cl? Will there be a combination of three products: NH4Cl + NH3 + MgCl2?

Comment: What is NH3? What do you know about its properties? Will it react with HCl? Well, of course, if we don't have enough of the latter, there will be all sorts of "underreacted" ("недореагировавших") products.